# Mysql set value with array

Tags: php, mysql

Is there possibility to update MySql table if ids in array like `$ids=['key1'=>'value1','key2'=>'value']`. `$ids` keys are ids in MySql table!

I can loop through `$ids` and do something like

```
foreach($ids as $key=>$value)
  do_query(UPDATE table SET column=$value WHERE $id=$key);
```

But want something to do all updates in one query,not to do `count($ids)` queries!

Comment: No  .you can't do all the updates  in one query  .. . you must  use a loop ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$idsIn='';
$ids=['key1'=>'value1','key2'=>'value'];
$case='';
foreach($ids as $key=>$value){
  $idsIn.=($idsIn=='')?"'$key'":','."'$key'";
  $case.=" WHEN '$key' THEN '$value'";
}

$sql = "UPDATE table set column= (CASE id $case END) WHERE id in($idsIn)";
```

return:

```
UPDATE table set column= (CASE id  WHEN 'key1' THEN 'value1' WHEN 'key2' THEN 'value' END) WHERE id in('key1','key2')
```

Comment: this is what i want! One more question, if I have array about 200 or more ids this will be faster way or faster way will be if i had 200 queries one for each ids,and database is large(more than 1.000.000 rows)?

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through a for to generate a giant string containing your statement, and in every loop, you would add another condition for the WHERE clause. Something like this:

```
$length = count($ids);
$statement = "UPDATE table set column=$value";
for ($i = 0; $i<$length; $i++){
if ($i == 0){ //checking if it is the first loop
$statement.= " WHERE $id = $ids[$i]";
}
else{
$statement.= " OR $ id = $ids[$i]";
}
}
```

Then you would execute your query based on $statement. I believe it's not the best thing to do, but i believe it would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to generate a coma separated string with the ids you want to update, from the array you already have, like "1,2,3,4,5" with this you can do a batch update in mysql like this:

```
update table
set column = 'new value'
where id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Just generate this query as a string and concatenate the ids and execute it, in php.